# What is the algorithm behind Cassandra's token function?

Tags: algorithm, cassandra, token, partition, murmurhash

The Token function in my driver doesn't support a composite partition key, but it works very well with a single partition key, it takes a binary in 8 bits form as an input and pass it to murmur3 hash function and extract the 64-signed-little-integer (Token) from the result of murmur3 and ignore any extra binary buffer.

So my hope is to generate the binary for a composite partition key and then pass it to murmur3 as usual, an algorithm or bitwise operations will be really helpful or at least a source in any programming language.

I don't mean murmur3 part, only the token side which converts/mixes the composite partition key and outputs raw bytes in binary form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to my question :The Algorithm to compute the token for a composite partition key : 
Primary_key((text, int)) -> therefore the partition key is a composite_partition_key (text, int).

Example : a row with composite_partition_key ('hello', 1)

Applying the algorithm :

**1- lay-out the components of the composite partition key in big-endian (16 bits) presentation :**

first_component = 'hello' ->  68 65 6c 6c 6f

sec_component = 1 -> 00 00 00 01

68 65 6c 6c 6f 00 00 00 01

**2- add two-bytes length of component before each component**

first_component = 'hello', length= 5-> ***00 05*** 68 65 6c 6c 6f

sec_component = 1, therefore length= 4 -> ***00 04*** 00 00 00 01

***00 05*** 68 65 6c 6c 6f ***00 04*** 00 00 00 01

**3- add zero-value after each component**

first_component = 'hello' -> ***00 05*** 68 65 6c 6c 6f  ***00***

sec_component = 1 -> ***00 04*** 00 00 00 01 ***00***

**4- result**

**00 05** 68 65 6c 6c 6f ***00*** **00 04** 00 00 00 01 ***00***

now pass the result as whatever binary base your murmur3 function understand (make sure it's cassandra variant).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the drivers since they have generate the token to find the correct coordinator. https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/8be7570a3c7fbba773ae2581bbf26e8196e7d6fb/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/Token.java#L112

Its slightly different than the typical murmur3 due to a bug when it was made and inability to change it without breaking existing clusters. So I would recommend copying it from them or better yet, use the existing drivers to find the token.

Comment: Hey Chris, I am developing a driver in pure elixir and it does support murmur3 (cassandra variant), so i think my issue lay in the token function side (before the hashing part?), right now i can easily hash any single partition key, but not a multi column partition key. Unfortunately am not a java guy, can you please guide me to the token part .. which equal system.token(column_pk_1, column_pk_2, etc), i just want the ability to generate the bytes for a composite partition key and then pass it to murmur3, or that will not work and need some modification at the hash function side? Thanks

Comment: know any other languages? theres python, js etc that are already written and well tested (ie https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver/blob/707953f52709fc507f07edb18659f2e2d9f4d22e/lib/tokenizer.js)

Comment: Yeah i know python ruby c and rust, will check the client drivers in those languages , Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/datastax/ruby-driver/blob/master/ext/cassandra_murmur3/cassandra_murmur3.c